# javascript couldn't apply find on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code

turn false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

I got error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $thisTR.find is not a function
```

this is the code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert element to `jQuery` Object

```
$thisTR = $(this) // not just this
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/607y6qdx/11/)

Comment: now i got error Uncaught TypeError: value.indexOf is not a function could you help please . this is the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/607y6qdx/12/

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Because you are not reading the value....You are using indexOf on a jQuery object. DEBUG YOUR CODE! console.log is your friend.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I've done small refactoring https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/607y6qdx/15/ I hope it will be helpful for you